# Calling a non-static method with constructors using objects from a different class

Tags: java, constructor

I am way deep into Java which I am pretty much unaware off. But few days of reading has led me to this understanding - I cannot call a non-static method from a a method of a different class.

So, I have a non-static method inside a class (ClassA) with a constructor. Lets call this MethodA.

And in MethodB in ClassB, I am doing this,

```
MethodB{
public static CommandControl ab;
ClassA objectA = new ClassA(ab) 
objectA.MethodA(String S)
}
```

Now, I have a NullPointerException when the control goes inside ClassA since the value of ab = null.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Make sure `ab` is not null of course. Give it a value before it is used.

Comment: *"I cannot call a non-static method from a a method of a different class"* - This is a misleading statement.  You *can* call a non-static method from anywhere, as long as you have an instance of such an object on which to call it.  *"the value of ab = null"* - Because you never initialized it to anything.

Comment: you can't have a NullPointerException there, because that code will never compile. Could you please show an actual code sample where you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding:

> I cannot call a non-static method from a a method of a different class.

is wrong.

If you have created the object of the class containing the non-static method, you can call it.

You get a null pointer exception because the constructor of the ClassA does something with the CommandControl ab. And that ab is null in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C/C++, Java requires you to explicitly create an instance using `new` keyword.

Your statement `public static CommandControl ab;` should be updated as `public static CommandControl ab = new CommandControl();`

Comment: I get Cannot instantiate the type CommandControl. CommandControl is an abstract class in my case.

Comment: @SriramIlango please take some time to study the basics.

Comment: In such case, you should instantiate one of its child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully clear , so I'll try to do some assumptions:

does class B is a child class of A?
and does method B is called in the constractor of B?
if so, then the variables are not instantiated yet since you are in the constractor.